# Отправка post запроста из EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Пытаюсь отправить model в post запросе. Как это сделать?

```
   import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  pageBinding: "content.page",
  perPageBinding: "content.perPage",
  totalPagesBinding: "content.totalPages"

  actions: {
    excelDownoload: function(user) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://list-share-shop.loc/app_dev.php/admin-api/v1/excel.json",
        data: model(param)
      });

    },
  }

});
```

Делаю вот так

и так

```
<button class="btn btn-violet" {{action "excelDownoload"}}>Generate report</button>
```

и в ответ model not defined

Answer (score 1):

Мало как-то информации в предоставили. Есть ли ссылка на репозиторий?
Что такое param в model(param)?

Вообще-то не рекомендуется использовать контроллеры. От них же отказываются.

Comment: Я переписываю уже готовый проект на EmberJS и вообще не разбираюсь что и как.... https://bitbucket.org/sspsoft/lss-admin

Comment: нет доступа к репозиторию

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, функция `model()` не существует. Она в файле и в области видимости неопределенна ... 
сделай так

```
$.ajax({
    type: "........",
    url: "...........",
    data: {
        "ключ":значение......,
        "ключ":значение......,
        "ключ":значение......,
        "ключ":значение......
    }
});
```